# Which PDE does v fullfill?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> > Let u be a solution of the PDE
> >     $$
> > u_{xy}+au_x+b u_y+cu=0,~~~~~~~~~~~~~~a,b,c=const.~~~~~(*)
> > $$
> >     Consider
> >     $$
> > v(x,y):=u(x,y)\exp(bx+ay).
> > $$
> >     Find the PDE which $v$ fullfills.

Could you please give me a hint how to find that PDE?

(*) is a linear PDE of degree 2, right? Do I have to find the normal form?

As you see: I do not really know how to solve this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$u(x,y)=v(x,y)\exp(-bx-ay)$.  Now differentiate that, and combine the results of $u_{xy}$ and so on, to add up to 0 on the right-hand side

Comment: You mean I have to determine $u_{x}, u_y,u_{xx},u_{yy},u_{xy},u_{yx}$ for $u(x,y)=v(x,y)\exp(-bx-ay)$ ?

Comment: No, just $u_{xy}, u_x, u_y$.  Then feed your results into the original equation.  $\exp(-bx-ay)$ should be a common factor

Comment: If I did not make a mistake, then $v$ fullfills the PDE $v_{xy}+(c-ab)\cdot v=0$.